# linking glew32.lib with GLEW_STATIC definition on visual studio 2015 complain error LNK200

Tags: glew

I had add glew32.lib to linker->input->additional Dep, and add GLEW_STATIC definition to preprocessor. I am sure this setting is correctly. but vs show me linking error.  does it need any other setting?  I had google this problem for 3 days, and did get any help!

```
    1>------ Build started: Project: demo, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
    1>libtiff-2015.lib(tif_win32.obj) : warning LNK4075: ignoring '/EDITANDCONTINUE' due to '/SAFESEH' specification
    1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
    1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLViewImpl-desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindFramebuffer
    1>cocox.lib(CCFrameBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindFramebuffer
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLViewImpl-desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindRenderbuffer
    1>cocox.lib(CCFrameBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBindRenderbuffer
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLViewImpl-desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewCheckFramebufferStatus
    1>cocox.lib(CCFrameBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewCheckFramebufferStatus
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLViewImpl-desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteFramebuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCFrameBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteFramebuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLViewImpl-desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteRenderbuffers
    ....................
    1>cocox.lib(CCFrameBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenFramebuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLViewImpl-desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenRenderbuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCFrameBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenRenderbuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLViewImpl-desktop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenerateMipmap
   ........................
    1>cocox.lib(ccGLStateCache.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDisableVertexAttribArray
    1>cocox.lib(CCCameraBackgroundBrush.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewEnableVertexAttribArray
    1>cocox.lib(CCMeshCommand.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewEnableVertexAttribArray
    1>cocox.lib(CCVertexAttribBinding.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewEnableVertexAttribArray
    ................................
    1>cocox.lib(CCRenderer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferData
    1>cocox.lib(CCDrawNode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferData
    1>cocox.lib(CCTextureAtlas.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferData
    1>cocox.lib(CCCameraBackgroundBrush.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewBufferData
    1>cocox.lib(CCVertexIndexBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCRenderer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCDrawNode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCTextureAtlas.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCCameraBackgroundBrush.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewDeleteBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCVertexIndexBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCRenderer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCDrawNode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCTextureAtlas.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCCameraBackgroundBrush.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGenBuffers
    1>cocox.lib(CCRenderer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewMapBuffer
    1>cocox.lib(CCTextureAtlas.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewMapBuffer
   .........................
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLProgram.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetActiveAttrib
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLProgram.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewGetActiveUniform
    .....................
    1>cocox.lib(CCGLProgram.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewUniformMatrix4fv
    1>cocox.lib(CCVertexIndexBuffer.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___glewIsBuffer
    1>G:\code\cpp\cocoxgame\vs2015\demo\Debug\demo.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 73 unresolved externals
    ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 5 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: You can statically compile glew into your project.
Add glew.h and glew.c to you project source files.

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake, this "glew32.lib" just a import library for glew32.dll. must replace glew32.lib by glew32s.lib.